# Access variables outside a class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

How do I access things outside of a class method in rails? I get an error like undefined method do_something_else

```
module Thing
  def self.do_something
    do_something_else
  end

  def do_something_else

  end
end
```

Comment: do_something is a  class  method and calls Thing.do_something..... do_something_else is a instance method and you need an instance of model..
my_thing = Thing.new
my_thing.do_something_else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a good reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13067901/3893710) that shows the difference between `class_methods/singleton_methods` and `instance_methods`.

In your case, you cannot access the instance method(`do_something_else`) without an instance.
To solve this, you have to include the module in a class and use an instance of that class.

```
module Thing
  def self.do_something
    Logic.new.do_something_else
  end

  def do_something_else
    #perform the logic and actions here
  end
end

class Logic
  include Thing
end
```

If you would like to think of it differently though, here's what I'd propose:

```
module Thing
  def self.do_something_else
    # perform your logic and actions here
  end

  def do_something
    # this is possible because do_something_else is defined on the module Thing
    Thing.do_something_else
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def self.do_something
  Thing.new.do_something_else
end
```