# Rspec "NoMethodError" from nested module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm running into a weird error:

Class:

```
module AnimalSanctuary
  module AnimalInspector
    class AnimalPicker

   def initialize(number_of_animals, ids)
     @number_of_animals = number_of_animals
     @ids = ids
    end

     ...
     def pick_animals(animal)
     end 
  end
end
```

test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe AnimalSanctuary::AnimalInspector::AnimalPicker do
  describe ".pick_animals" do
    context "pick an available animal" do
      it "returns animal name" do
        expect(AnimalSanctuary::AnimalInspector::AnimalPicker.pick_animals("Dog")).to eq("Dog")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `pick_animals' for AnimalSanctuary::AnimalInspector::AnimalPicker:Class
```

Rspec calls the class but not the method which has stumped me. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `pick_animals` is an **instance method**.

To call it, you will need to instantiate an object of the class using the `new` method as shown below. I have passed in random values to your initializer (1, [1,2]) however you can set them as you like.:

```
number_of_animals = 1
ids = [1,2]
AnimalSanctuary::AnimalInspector::AnimalPicker.new(number_of_animals, ids).pick_animals("Dog")
```

Otherwise, to call it the way you are calling it, you will need to redefine it as a **class method** by using `self.pick_animals` as shown below:

```
module AnimalSanctuary
  module AnimalInspector
    class AnimalPicker

     ...
     def self.pick_animals(animal)
     end 
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks I updated my question. I have an initialize method. Is there a way I can bypass the initialize method and call the method? I get the error that I need to initialize it

Comment: You can pass in some values to initialize it (I have updated my answer to include some dummy values). To call it without initialising it, you will need to change this method to a class method (using the self. definition)

Comment: This is discussed here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067831/calling-ruby-method-without-instantiating-class

Answer (score 0):

yeah `pick_animals` is an instance method.

you can use the following in your rspec

```
expect_any_instance_of(nimalSanctuary::AnimalInspector::AnimalPicker).to receive(:pick_animals).with("dogs").to_eq("Dog")
```

Hope this helps